# UITableView Header background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

There are questions and answers for how to change the background color of Header titles in UITableView. These work when a class directly inherits from UITableView. However, when I embed a UITableView as a child of a UIViewController, the same approach of changing the background color does not appear to work.

Can you please see the code below and let me know how I can do this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var table: UITableView!
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test row"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section Title"
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    1
}

// One way to change the header color
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.backgroundColor = .green
}

// Another way
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let vw = UIView()
    vw.backgroundColor = .red
    return vw
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.maxX/3, y: view.frame.maxY/3, width: view.frame.width/2, height: view.frame.height/2))
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    table.dataSource = self
    
    view.addSubview(table)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` is a delegate method check [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview)  , so you need to add

```
table.delegate = self
```

Comment: @ Sh_Khan Thanks ... ugh, so simple!

For other, I did not set the table's delegate to self.  I needed to add the line
    table.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to conform to UITableViewDelegate for titleForHeaderInSection, willDisplayHeaderView, and viewForHeaderInSection.

You'll need to conform to UITableViewDataSource for numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAt, numberOfRowsInSection.

In your viewDidLoad():

```
table.delegate = self
table.dataSource = self
```